# How to obtain _ts in CosmosDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a Posts collection on CosmosDB and each post needs to have an insertion date. Since cosmosDB already inserts the _ts field on the documents, I thought that might use that value instead of inserting my own timestamp manually. However, when I try to put an object (in Java) into the collection I get the following error: 400 Unrecognized field "_ts" (class scc.models.User), not marked as ignorable.

Is there a way to obtain _ts in the objects (I'm not talking about a query to obtain _ts of a specific object but instead for _ts be one of the variables of the object when I retrieve it from CosmosDB).

Comment: _ts comes in all objects when you query

Comment: It does not. Thays why I'm having a problem, because I want it.

Comment: it cannot be, what is the sdk you are using?

Comment: Can't help you without any sample code you are using.Would you please post more details about it? Such as the complete error log or sample code(put object into cosmos)

Comment: I'm confused about the question: are you trying to *insert* `_ts` along with other properties, when you save a document? If so, that would be an issue since the underscored properties are Cosmos DB system properties.

Comment: I have a Java Class that I want to insert and retrieve from cosmos. This class needs a timestamp, however, since cosmos has the _ts already, I want it to be a variable of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a property
`@JsonProperty("_ts") private String timeStamp;` on your User model. If you give it a value when updating (marshalling) it seems to be ignored, but for transparency you could add `@JsonIgnore`  on the timeStamp field as well. If you want to do more low level adjustments you could also provide your own version of the `cosmosdbObjectMapper` bean (see `AbstractCosmosConfiguration`).

Answer (score 0):

I am using the C# SDK (I know you are Java - but maybe it's analogous.)

After retrieving a document, I can access the system property _ts as a DateTime via the property `Resource.TimeStamp` (within namespace Microsoft.Azure.Documents.)